# Pass div element into JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, html

Is it possible to pass a div/span element into a JavaScript function? I know it's possible to set a unique ID to to div/span and fetch it that way but it would be cleaner for me if I just could pass the whole element somehow. Also this needs to be done when the page is loaded so the `onclick` event is not working in this case either.

**Example:**

```
<div>
    <script>myFunction(div element should be passed trough here);</script>              
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass it into a function when it's loaded? You should do any processing after the whole page has loaded.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Why can't you give the div an ID or class?

Comment: @DanielTovesson you're update can also be solved with my answer.. set the inner div id to "myID4324123" where the number is the relevant timestamp. i can create the full example if you post your timer code

Comment: Yeah, that's what I went on doing. Doesn't seem to be a way to do this without setting an ID

Comment: But you still downvoted everyone as a good mesure right ?

Comment: I didn't downvote anyone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a `div` with an `id` attribute as a child of your wanted `div`. Create a `script` inside that once loaded fetches the inner `div` an uses `parentNode` to get the initial `div`:

```
<div>
    <div id="myID"><script>myFunction();</script></div>             
</div>
```

And in the javascript:

```
  function myFunction(){
        var element = document.getElementById('myID');
        var wantedDiv = element.parentNode; // this will give you the parent div so you can do what ever you want with it
        // do something here with wantedDiv
    }
```

I've added a [**working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TBX6W/1/)

Comment: `that just might work`...does it work?  Have you fiddled it?  onload is not supported by divs

Answer (score -2):

In this case, the `this` case will be the `window` element.

If you want to get your `<div>` element :

`var myDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');`

If you have more than one div, you will have to add an id or a class like this :

- Set an id :

  `<div id="myId"></div>`
- Get an element by id :

`var myDiv = document.getElementById('myId');`

- Set a class :

  `<div class="myClass"></div>`
- Get an element by class :

`var myDiv = document.getElementsByClass('myClass');`

Ones you have the myDiv variable you could do something like this :

```
myDiv.onload = function(event) {
    // "this" is your div element
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: It it possible to make `this` the div element somehow? Like when you pass it trough `onclick` but in some kind of load-event?

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it helps !

Comment: Same thing as with my answer, setting id or class does not seem to be an option.

Comment: You can try to select your div with the `document.getElementsByTagName()` method. But if you can't use selectors like `id`'s, `class`'s or `tag names`, you can't do much. I don't think what you want to do is possible.